# export material ui themed package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui, rollupjs

I want to create a new npm package where i can export all @material-ui/core components but themed my way. Currently using typescript and rollup, but failing. This is my code

index.ts

```
export { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@ripley-ui/core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "module": "build/index.esm.js",
  "types": "build/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "storybook:export": "build-storybook",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^13.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^8.1.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.43",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "rollup": "^2.21.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.27.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  external: ["react", "@material-ui/core"],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    resolve(),
    typescript({
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      clean: true
    }),
    commonjs(),
  ]
};
```

and tsconfing.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "storybook-static",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

and the error it gets when importing Button into a new app is

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Help please!

**UPDATE**

I made another test, this time creating and exporting a new component made by me, and still gets the same invalid hook call error, heres the code!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { TestComponentProps } from "./TestComponent.types";


const TestComponent: React.FC<TestComponentProps> = ({ theme }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('prueba')
  return (
  <div
    data-testid="test-component"
    className={`test-component test-component-${theme}`}
  >
    <h2>{state}</h2>
  </div>
)};

export default TestComponent;
```

so maybe is my bundler or compiler problem?

Comment: You should check again, what are your components using hooks like ```makeStyles()```?

Comment: @Michael yes, all material-ui components have this hook makeStyles(), but dont know how is making it wrong

Comment: Can you show me the code that is using ```makeStyles()```?

Comment: @Michael here is the documentation of makeStyles() https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook BUT, i made another test, i've updated above so you can see my dumb component try with hooks, and still makes the same invalid hook call error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after investigating a lil bit more, i found out that is not your bundlers error (nor webpack, parcel or rollup). To fix this issue, you just have to publish your build into npm and install it from there (not locally) and voila, it works. cheers

Comment: Anyway  idea why that's the case? How do we locally develop it?

Comment: That's a good question and I would like to know the answer to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Excluding `react` and `react-dom` from `devDependencies` helped me to resolve this error